# How can you manually set the DataContext for the items of an ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, binding, datacontext, itemscontrol

I'd like to be able to manually set the DataContext of the container used for the items of an ItemControl?

is this possible?

(I don't want to do this using a converter for the ItemsSource as the collection changes, and ideally I'd like to be able to do it in some kind of custom ItemsControl as it will be used frequently)

```
<l:CustomItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; private set; } 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<object>() { 6, "Dog", DateTime.Now };

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I thought I could do something like below, but it doesn't have any affect as it appears the DataContext is set again afterwards

```
public class CustomItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        var presenter = element as ContentPresenter;
        presenter.DataContext = 5;

        // below would be some binding that is set up on some dynamic property of item
        // presenter.SetBinding(ContentPresenter.DataContextProperty, new Binding());
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a really odd approach. Why do you want to do this in the first place? Sounds like an XY Problem to me.

Comment: I think you're right, so I have presented the problem instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003270/using-icustomtypedescriptor-with-an-itemscontrol