# Using ICustomTypeDescriptor with an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, icustomtypedescriptor

I'm implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor so that I can create types with dynamic properties at runtime, however, instead of using the ICustomTypeDescriptor with a DataGrid which is how most people seem to use it, I'm wanting to use it with an ItemsControl.

Below is the guts of the application. (sorry, it's a lot of code)

```
public class BindableTypeDescriptor : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string _propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName));
        }
    }

    class BindablePropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
        public override Type PropertyType { get { return m_type; } }
        public override Type ComponentType { get { return null; } }

        public BindablePropertyDescriptor(BindableTypeDescriptor _owner, Type _type, string _name)
            : base(_name, null)
        {
            m_owner = _owner;
            m_type = _type;
            m_name = _name;
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object _value)
        {
            m_owner[m_name] = _value;
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return m_owner[m_name];
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {

        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        BindableTypeDescriptor m_owner;
        Type m_type;
        string m_name;
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> Properties { get { return m_properties; } }

    public string GetComponentName() 
    { 
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true); 
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent() 
    { 
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true); 
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return m_properties;
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        return ((ICustomTypeDescriptor)this).GetProperties(null);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(
            m_properties.Select(e => new BindablePropertyDescriptor(this, e.Value != null ? e.Value.GetType() : typeof(object), e.Key))
            .ToArray());
    }

    public object this[string _name]
    {
        get { return m_properties[_name]; }
        set 
        {
            m_properties[_name] = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(_name);
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> m_properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}

    public class Element 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string _propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class StringElement : Element
{
    string m_value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
        set
        {
            m_value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}

public class NumberElement : Element
{
    int m_value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return m_value; }
        set
        {
            m_value = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public BindableTypeDescriptor CustomType { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        CustomType = new BindableTypeDescriptor();
        CustomType["Name"] = new StringElement() { Value = "Dave" };
        CustomType["Age"] = new NumberElement() { Value = 5 };

        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
        CustomType["Name"] = new StringElement() { Value = "Fred" };
        CustomType["Age"] = new NumberElement() { Value = 6 };
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CustomType.Properties}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Content="{Binding Key}"/>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value}" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:StringElement}">
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:NumberElement}">
                            <Slider Value="{Binding Value}" Minimum="0" Maximum="50"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that with the above implementation, the ItemsControl doesn't update when I change a properties value (see OnMouseDoubleClick), which is to be expected as I'm binding to the initial "CustomType.Properties" when I should really be binding to each property by name. I can't do the latter though as I don't know the property names until runtime.

Therefore, I assume I need to be doing the binding dynamically in code behind, but I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Seems to me you'd be much better off creating an `ObservableCollection<SomeKindOfPropertyViewModel>` rather than binding to a Dictionary. Dictionaries are not observable and thus DataBinding doesn't play too well with them.

Comment: You could set up the bindings in code-behind (or in a MultiBinding), but that is a rabbit-hole to follow.  Easier would be to use an "observable dictionary" implementation ... but then, if you're doing that, then it seems you wouldn't need the custom type.  But then, as HighCore is saying, why not just use a collection of objects with "Key" and "Value" properties?